# Is there some function of $n$ that is a multiply of $\phi(n^2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function

Given $n = pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime and $\phi(n^2) = (p^2-p)(q^2-q)$ (The Euler Totient function). Is there some combination of $n$s such that $\phi(n^2)|f(n)$

$f$ can be anything (greater than$\phi(n^2)$)given it only uses $n$ and not $p$ or $q$ separately and results in an integer for the input of $n$.

I have tried to find some such $f$ by manipulating $\phi(n^2)$ but haven't had any luck.

Anyway of showing such an $f$ doesn't exist would also be helpful
Thanks

Edit:
I am trying to adapt this answer here:
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/58047/equality-check-in-homomorphic-encryption

where I am taking$\mod n^2$ rather than$\mod p$  I am looking to replace the $p-1$ in $1 - (A - B)^{p-1}$ with $f(n)$ that still returns 0 if $A \neq B \mod n^2$. to do this I am applying:

Euler’s Theorem: Let $m \in N$. For any $a ∈ Z$ such that $hcf(a, m) =
1$, we have $a^
{\phi(m)} ≡ 1 \mod m$, where $φ(m)$ is the Euler totient function.

I understand that this will occasionally fail (i.e. if $A-B = p \mod n) which is ok for me

Since I will be applying this $f(n)$ to check if $A=B$ I need it to be computationally efficient (e.g. in time polynomial in $\log n$) without knowing $p$,$q$. so an $f$ requiring the decomposition of $n$ won't work as this would take too long/ completely remove the point of the encryption

Comment: Let $f(n)=f(pq)=k(p^2-p)(q^2-q)$ for some positive integer $k$.

Comment: sorry, but how is $f$ in terms of $n$. $f$ can't include $p$ or $q$ seperately

Comment: But $n=pq$ always, or not? We have $\phi(n^2)=n^2+n-(p+q)n$, and we cannot express it easily only in terms of $n$.

Comment: Yes but assuming p and q are not known. This is for cryptography where p and q are massive so finding them is hard so I am looking for a function that uses only n as this is given

Comment: does $f(n) = 0$ work?

Comment: Why do you think there is such a function $f(n)$, which is of any use? Why can't we take $f(n)=\phi(n^2)$. This is only in $n$.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified $f(n)>\phi(n^2)$

Comment: How about $(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor )!^2$

Comment: Then also $f(n)=2\phi(n^2)$ is possible. I think you need to clarify what you really want in the end, and how you want to apply it.

Comment: Yeah that's also possible I guess, I was thinking that maybe an expression that sort of didn't talk about prime factorization was sought after or something.

Comment: I will add more to the question

Comment: You should probably specify in the question that you want $f(n)$ to be computable efficiently (e.g. in time polynomial in $\log n$) without knowing $p,q$.

Comment: yeah for using $\phi(n^2)$  I was trying to avoid as the only expression for it that I know uses the prime decomposition of n which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: $\phi(n^2)=n\phi(n).................$

Comment: This requires $\phi(n)$ which relies on p and q or at least a speeding factorisation of n which I think isn't possible

Comment: [Cross-posted to crypto-SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/92266/555), where it might be more on-topic

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure where to put it

Comment: @Daniel I figured that out too, but in my case only after looking at http://oeis.org/A002618

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there some combination of $n$s such that $\phi(n^2) | f(n)$

One would hope that there is no efficient way to compute a nontrivial $f(n)$ without apriori knowledge of the factorization of $n$ (or some equivalent knowledge, such as the knowledge of $\phi(n)$)

The reason is that knowledge of any (nonhuge) multiple of $\phi(n)$ allows you to efficiently factor $n$; hence you would have just broken RSA (and Paillier).

The method to factor is fairly straight-forward; if you know a value $z = k \phi(n)$ (for some unknown $k > 0$); $z$ has the property that $g^z \equiv 1 \pmod n$ for any $g$ relatively prime to $n$.

What you do is compute the odd value $w = z / 2^{\lambda}$ (where $\lambda$ is number of factors of 2 within $z$; because $\phi(n)$ is even, we have $\lambda > 0$), and then for a random $g$, we compute $g^w \bmod n$; if that is neither 1 nor -1 (aka $n-1$), we repeatedly square the result $\lambda$ times.  If one of the squarings results in a 1 but the previous value was not $-1$, then that gives the factorization, becaues if $g^2 \equiv 1 \bmod n$, and $g$ is neither $1$ nor $-1$, then $\gcd( g-1, n)$ and $\gcd( g+1, n)$ are nontrivial factors of $n$.

It is straight-forward to show that this yields nontrivial factors for at least half of the random $g$ values; this is also efficient, and so is a practical factorization method (assuming that we know $z$ in the first place)

---

Also, you are doing this in order to generate a Paillier based function that converts (most) nonzero values to 1 and zero values to 0.  With such a function, Paillier would become a fully homomorphic function (that is, you can compute any [1] function homomorphically.  We can see this because we could generate a two input NAND function homomorphically by, given $E_k(A)$ and $E_k(B)$ (where both $A, B \in \{0, 1\}$) by computing $E_k(2-A-B)$ (which Paillier allows us to do), and then applying your magic function to the result.  And, since NAND is complete, that means we can express any circuit as a series of NAND functions.

A Paillier-based fully homomorphic encryption would be a big deal; it doesn't look likely in practice.

[1]: Well, anything that can be described with a bounded circuit, which turns out to be just about anything we care about in practice

Answer (score 1):

A bit more simplistically, for semiprime $n=pq$, $\phi(n^2)=p(p-1)q(q-1)=pq(pq-p-q+1)=n^2-n(p+q)+n$

In order to construct a function based solely on $n$, you are faced with explicitly knowing or discovering something about $p$ and $q$ based only on your knowledge of $n$. As poncho indicated in his answer, the problem devolves to factoring $n$.

Comment: However, he isn't asking for a way to compute $\phi(n^2)$, but rather $k \phi(n^2)$, for potentially a huge $k$; this large $k$ value blocks straight-forward algebraic approaches...

Comment: Actually, he's asking if there are two functions, $f(n)$ and $g(n)$, such that $f(n)=g(n)\cdot \phi(n^2)$. The possibility that $g(n)=k$ a constant can probably be dismissed. Finding a suitable $g(n)$ that is not dependent on factoring $n$ does not seem likely to me, but I have no proof that it can't be done.

Comment: I had assumed that $k$ was dependent on $n$, so we're on the same page there.  As for proof that you can't find a $g(n)$ that doesn't depend on factoring, well, see my answer...